# CSS class working only once on validation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have defined a CSS class which looks like this -

```
@-webkit-keyframes wiggle {
    0% {-webkit-transform:rotate(2deg);}
    50% {-webkit-transform:rotate(-2deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform:rotate(2deg);}
}

@-moz-keyframes wiggle {
    0% {-moz-transform:rotate(2deg);}
    50% {-moz-transform:rotate(-2deg);}
    100% {-moz-transform:rotate(2deg);}
}

@keyframes wiggle {
    0% {transform:rotate(2deg);}
    50% {transform:rotate(-2deg);}
    100% {transform:rotate(2deg);}
}

.doWiggle {
    -webkit-animation: wiggle 0.2s;
    -moz-animation: wiggle 0.2s;
}
```

In JavaScript, I have this function -

```
function validateOnSubmit() {

    var isValid = true;

    if (document.getElementById("password").value.length <= 5) {
        isValid = false;
        document.getElementById("alert").className = "doWiggle";
    }

    return isValid;

}
```

The `validateOnSubmit()` function is implemented in the form as `onsubmit="return validateOnSubmit()"`

The problem is that, the wiggling effect happens for only **one** click of the `submit` button. The wiggling effect **does not happen** if I click the `submit` button the second time or consecutive times.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: share html or just make jsfiddle for this ?

Comment: class `doWiggle` is already added to the element. Try to remove it, and add second time.

Comment: Try removing the class after the animation is complete or before you set the className.  I think the animation only runs when the element first gets the class so when you run it again, it doesn't work because it already has the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not removing the className after the animation has run. Here is a fiddle with the corrected behavior or removing the className: https://jsfiddle.net/4fqLhbjx/1/

Basically what I did was I added this to the `if` condition:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("alert").className = document.getElementById("alert").className.replace('doWiggle', '');
}, 300);
```

I chose `300` to make sure the animation had time to finish cleanly.

Comment: @MavenMaverick you looked at the fiddle I posted and it isn't working? I see the button wiggling every time the password box has less than 6 characters in it. If the fiddle isn't working can you tell me what browser you're using so I can try to replicate? It works for me on both Chrome and Firefox